# javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame

Tags: java, speech-recognition, google-cloud-speech, speech-recognition-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm creating a run-able jar from a project in Eclipse, which consist of a basic sample code for speech recognition using cloud speech. Anyhow the problem is when I run the code from Eclipse it works fine, but when I create a run-able jar and execute it, it throws me the following exception:

> "  javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format
>   PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not
>   supported. ".

Hers's my code:

```java
public static void streamingMicRecognize() throws Exception {

  ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responseObserver = null;
  try (SpeechClient client = SpeechClient.create()) {

    responseObserver =
        new ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse>() {
          ArrayList<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();

          public void onStart(StreamController controller) {}

          public void onResponse(StreamingRecognizeResponse response) {
            responses.add(response);
          }

          public void onComplete() {
            for (StreamingRecognizeResponse response : responses) {
              StreamingRecognitionResult result = response.getResultsList().get(0);
              SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
              System.out.printf("Transcript : %s\n", alternative.getTranscript());
            }
          }

          public void onError(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t);
          }
        };

    ClientStream<StreamingRecognizeRequest> clientStream =
        client.streamingRecognizeCallable().splitCall(responseObserver);

    RecognitionConfig recognitionConfig =
        RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
            .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
            .setLanguageCode("en-US")
            .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
            .build();
    StreamingRecognitionConfig streamingRecognitionConfig =
        StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setConfig(recognitionConfig).build();

    StreamingRecognizeRequest request =
        StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
            .setStreamingConfig(streamingRecognitionConfig)
            .build(); // The first request in a streaming call has to be a config

    clientStream.send(request);
    // SampleRate:16000Hz, SampleSizeInBits: 16, Number of channels: 1, Signed: true,
    // bigEndian: false
    AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(16000, 16, 1, true, false);
    DataLine.Info targetInfo =
        new Info(
            TargetDataLine.class,
            audioFormat); // Set the system information to read from the microphone audio stream

    if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(targetInfo)) {
      System.out.println("Microphone not supported");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    // Target data line captures the audio stream the microphone produces.
    TargetDataLine targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
    targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
    targetDataLine.start();
    System.out.println("Start speaking");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Audio Input Stream
    AudioInputStream audio = new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine);
    while (true) {
      long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
      byte[] data = new byte[6400];
      audio.read(data);
      if (estimatedTime > 60000) { // 60 seconds
        System.out.println("Stop speaking.");
        targetDataLine.stop();
        targetDataLine.close();
        break;
      }
      request =
          StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
              .setAudioContent(ByteString.copyFrom(data))
              .build();
      clientStream.send(request);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
  }
  responseObserver.onComplete();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LiveStream ls = new LiveStream();
    try {ls.streamingMicRecognize();} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

This is a simple code for recognizing speech through streaming audio.

Comment: What is the command you use to build the JAR? Please update the question with it.

Comment: Hi boris , i used the eclipse export as runnable jar functionality to create the jar ...

Comment: I would recommend you to use Maven or Gradle for your project. It will allow you to build a runnable JAR as well as staying IDE agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue got resolved after i built a jar using maven by using package as goal.Thanks for the help :-D